# Mysql Join with filters

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: `MAINCOLOR` and `SUBCOLOR` with the data as:

```
MAINCOLOR :
MAINID  COLOR
1       RED
2       BLUE
3       GREEN

SUBCOLOR:
SUBID MAINID SUBCOLOR STATUS
1     1      PINK     0
2     1      ORANGE   1
3     2      VIOLET   1
```

I need a result set as:

```
MAINID  COLOR   SUBCOLOR
1       RED     ORANGE
2       BLUE    VIOLET
3       GREEN
```

Resultset should be a join of `MAINCOLOR` and `SUBCOLOR` using `MAINID`. Need child data having `status` as 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the result by using a `LEFT JOIN` between the `maincolor` and the `subcolor`.

The key is placing the filter of `status=1` on the `JOIN` condition.  Your code will be:

```
select m.mainid,
  m.color,
  s.subcolor
from maincolor m
left join subcolor s
  on m.mainid = s.mainid
  and s.status = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a031/2).

The `LEFT JOIN` will return all rows from the `maincolor` table and any matching rows in the `subcolor` table. Since you what to apply a `WHERE` to the data in the `subcolor` table, then you will want to move that filter to the `JOIN` condition to get the result.

Comment: Hurray. It worked. I was trying with a where clause, not resulting the required result. Thanks bluefeet.